# Get date with prior 30 days to current date

Tags: javascript, date

I try to subtract 30 days to current date and I always receive a negative number to day value. The most important thing is the format of the returned date, that must be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I know that there are similar questions like this but I couldn't find a solution.

This is what I've done so far..

```
  var date = new Date();

  var dd = date.getDate()-30;
  var mm = date.getMonth()+1;

  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
  } 
  if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
  } 
  var dateTo = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
```

The above code will return 2016-07- -10 for today date instead of 2016-07-21

Comment: Just to see if I got it right: You want today - 30 days?

Comment: If your are ok with using library - check http://momentjs.com/ . It is very usefull for this kind of problem

Comment: @n0m4d, yes I want to subtract 30 days from the current day

Comment: @Weedoze I can't use a library...

Comment: I agree with @Weedoze, have been using mommentjs for awhile and it does a great job in handling dates

Comment: I can't use mommentjs because I'm building scripts with google apps script...

Comment: The problem with your question is that you're conflating a subtraction problem, with a formatting problem.  Sort out the date 'value' first, and then you can use a standard date format approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are subtracting from a number that has NO connection to the date object. Changing it does nothing but change the number. You need to subtract the days from the date itself.

```js
var today = new Date();
var past30 = new Date();
past30.setDate(today.getDate()-30);
console.log(past30);
```

Comment: I already tried this and it returns me `Error: Cannot call method "substring" of null.` in the console

Comment: Why did you use 2 date objects?

Comment: @4castle because I felt like it?

Comment: This works fine.  Not sure how you're trying to run this Pavel.

Comment: I see that it runs in a jsfiddle, maybe it's because I'm using google script...Another issue is that the date format must be `YYYY-mm-dd` like I specified in the question

Comment: @PavelValeriu Well there is no substring in any of that code so the problem would be somewhere else.... So change it to be in that format like you did above....

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to find out why google script throws me that error

Comment: Fixed it by using only one date object:   
var past = new Date();

past.setDate(past.getDate()-30);

new Date(past);

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-30);
d = d.toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: can you explain what you did and why?

Comment: @depperm toISOString() returns the date object as a String with format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" then extract the date using slice. the replace is not needed there.

Comment: its best to include an explanation to any code you have in your answer

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!